# ロードバランサ　ワンアームツーアーム構成について

Tags: network

### テーマ、知りたいこと

ロードバランサーのワンアームとツーアーム構成について

### 背景、状況

ロードバランサのワンアーム構成とツーアーム構成について調べたのですがいまいち理解ができず、、
ワンアーム構成はサーバーと直接通信ができて
ツーアームだと直接通信ができない
みたいなことが書かれていてそれがなぜか分からないです、
あと、
ワンアームとツーアームのそれぞれのユースケースが分かず、、
どのような時に使いわければいいのでしょうか

どなたかご教授いただけたら幸いです。

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/oim154xn3zdakp) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)